# How do I properly configure Swagger so that Visual Studio creates "normal" code?

Tags: c#, rest, visual-studio-2017, azure-functions, swagger-2.0

I want the best experience for my consumers, and created a swagger endpoint for my function app. I just ran VS2017's add endpoint feature

And got a function call named `ApiTokenPolicyPublisherIDSpecificationIDpostAsync` ... a concatenation of the URL: /api/TokenPolicy/{PublisherID}/{SpecificationID} method POST + async.

[image]

Is there something I can do better with my swagger, or is this how VS just does its code? (if so, [that's disappointing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_O1hM-k3aUY))

Here is a [link to my swagger](https://pastebin.com/s1D2uVJc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the VS is converting your operationId in your swagger definition into the method calls

After updating the operation id in your sample swagger

```
operationId: '/api/TokenPolicy/{PublisherID}/{SpecificationID}/post'
```

to

```
operationId: 'CustomEnroll'
```

This is what i got

[image]